# Can someone explain me this code? About user input, scanner etc

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

Can someone explain to me how this code works?

It lets the user input numbers up until `1000`, then it prints the original inputted numbers, the even and the odd, all in a separate array. But I just don't understand the parts where there is `gem++` and `gem1++` when it outputs the even and odd not the number of the even and odd numbers.

And after putting this

```
double even[] = new double[gem];
double odd[] = new double [gem1];
```

why does it need to repeat `gem=0` and `gem1=0` again? I'm so sorry if I ask too many question, I'm just confused, I just learned java last week.

```
public class wutt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter no. of elements you want in array : ");
        int n = s.nextInt();

        if (1 <= n && n <= 1000) {

            double a[] = new double[n];
            int gem = 0, gem1 = 0;

            System.out.println("Enter all the elements : ");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                a[i] = s.nextInt();
                if (a[i] % 2 == 0)
                    gem++;
                else
                    gem1++;
            }

            double even[] = new double[gem];
            double odd[] = new double[gem1];

            gem = 0;
            gem1 = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
                    even[gem] = a[i];
                    gem++;
                } else {
                    odd[gem1] = a[i];
                    gem1++;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Original: " + Arrays.toString(a));
            System.out.println("Odd: " + Arrays.toString(odd));
            System.out.println("Even: " + Arrays.toString(even));

        } else
            System.out.print("Invalid input");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the program stops after the user enters a number greater than 1000 o less than 0 you need to add the `break` statement in your `if` condition.

```
if (size < 0 || size > 1000) {
    System.out.println("Size must be between 0 and 1000");
    break;
}
```

Comment: `break` is useful to break out of loops, the test for the number of elements is done before any loop `if (1 <= n && n <= 1000)` and since the method stops right after executing `if else` there is nothing to break out of. But if you where to inverse the if you could `return` instead of having all the logic inside an if

Comment: Yes, it's better this way.

Answer (score 0):

the code before `double even[] = new double[gem];
double odd[] = new double [gem1];` is trying to get the number of odds occurred and the number of even occurred and put all inputted elements in array `a`.
after all that ,now what we got is a array of numbers called `a` containing all the inputted elements. and two numbers called gem and gem1, which contains  the number of odds occurred and the number of even occurred.
so 
we get gem(numberOfEvens), gem1(numberOfOdds) and list `a`

next, we need to put all odds from `a` to a new array called odd[] with size gem1, and 
put all evens from `a` to a new array called even[] with size gem. at this point, the duty of variable gem1 and gem is done. they become useless.

now we need to go through the list and pick the odd and even out and put them in the array one by one in a sequential way. that's why we need two new variables with 0 initialized.
in this case, because gem and gem1 are useless aready, they are reassigned to help manipulate the tree arrays `a` , `odd[]` and `even[]`

Answer (score 0):

So the user inputs the number of elements he/she wants in the array (`n`)

```
double a[] = new double[n];   // a is the array that is initialised to accommodate n elements
int gem = 0, gem1 = 0;        // gem is the counter for "even" numbers and "gem1" the counter for odd numbers, and like every good counter, they start at 0

System.out.println("Enter all the elements : ");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {     // so we ask the user to input n elements
    a[i] = s.nextInt();           // here we read every input and put it in the a array
    if (a[i] % 2 == 0)            // if the new number is even
        gem++;                    // we increase the even counter "gem"
    else                          // otherwise, when it is an odd number
        gem1++;                   // we increase the odd counter
}

double even[] = new double[gem];  // now we create a new array where we want to hold all the even numbers, we do that by telling it how many even numbers we have counted before (gem)
double odd[] = new double[gem1];  // and a new array for all odd numbers (gem1 was our counter)

gem = 0;                          // now we reinitialise the counters, because we want to start from the beginning
gem1 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { // in order to copy all numbers from the a array into the two other arrays for even and odd numbers, we iterate over the whole length of the a array. i is the index for the "a" array
    if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {             // ever even number we encounter
        even[gem] = a[i];            // we put in the even array
        gem++;                       // while gem, the "even numbers counter" is our index for the "even" array
    } else {
        odd[gem1] = a[i];            // odd numbers are for the odd array
        gem1++;                      // while the former "odd numbers counter" now serves as our "odd" array index
    }
}
```

and that's pretty much it. First the user inputs all numbers in a single array and simply counts how many odd and how many even numbers where inputted,

then two new arrays are created, one for the even and one for the odd numbers and since we counted them, we know how big these two new arrays have to be.

And finally all numbers are again iterated over and put in their according array.
At the end you have 3 array, one that holds **all** numbers, one that holds the **even** numbers and one with only the **odd** numbers.

**EDIT**

here are a few minor changes you could make without changing the nature of that method:

```
double allNumbers[] = new double[n];  // "allNumbers" is way more specific than "a"
int oddCounter = 0;                   // "oddCounter" instead of "gem"
int evenCounter = 0;                  // numbers in variables like "gem1" is really bad practice, because numbers don't say anything about the nature of the variable

System.out.println("Enter all the elements : ");

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    allNumbers[i] = s.nextInt();
    if (allNumbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
        evenCounter++;
    } else {
        oddCounter++;
    }
}
// until here nothing changes but the names

double even[] = new double[evenCounter];
double odd[] = new double[oddCounter];

int oddIndex = 0;                   // and here we create new variables, instead of reusing old ones
int evenIndex = 0;                  // there is absolutely no performance gain in reusing primitives like this - it's just confusing
for (int i = 0; i < allNumbers.length; i++) {
    if (allNumbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
        even[evenIndex++] = allNumbers[i];   // the "++" can be done directly in the first expression. that's just to make it shorter.
    } else {
        odd[oddIndex++] = allNumbers[i];     // it is not more performant nor easier to read - just shorter
    }
}
```

**EDIT (again)**

This is how the arrays look like, say when you enter 4 numbers:

```
gem = 0
gem1 = 0
n = 4               // user said 4 
a = [ , , , ]       // array a is empty but holds the space for 4 numbers

a = [1, , , ]       // user enters 1
     ^
    i=0

gem1 = 1            // 1 is an odd number -> gem1++

a = [1,4, , ]       // user entered "4"
       ^
      i=1
gem = 1             // 4 is an even number -> gem++

a = [1,4,2, ]       // user entered "2"
         ^
        i=2
gem = 2             // 24 is an even number -> gem++

a = [1,4,2,7]       // user entered "7"
           ^
          i=3
gem1 = 2             // 7 is an odd number -> gem1++


then we fill the other arrays

even = [ , ]          // gem is 2, so we have 2 even numbers
odd  = [ , ]          // gem1 is 2, so we have 2 odd numbers

a = [1,4,2,7]
     ^ 
    i=0

odd[1, ]    // for i=0, a[i] is 1, which is an odd number

a = [1,4,2,7]
       ^ 
      i=1

even = [4, ]    // for i=1, a[i] is 4, which is an even number

a = [1,4,2,7]
         ^ 
        i=2

even = [4,2]    // for i=2, a[i] is 2, which is an even number

a = [1,4,2,7]
           ^ 
          i=3

odd = [1,7]    // for i=3, a[i] is 7, which is an odd number

and in the end you have

a    = [1,4,2,7]
even = [4,2]
odd  = [1,7]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!!!! Can I ask one last time, all I need is to print the original then even and odd numbers, why is it necessary to count the even and odd numbers first?  Or can I make this code shorter?

Comment: and why do we need gem++ in the last part?

Comment: sorry for the delay. Well in the last part you only have `i++` in your for-loop, but you also need to increment the index for the *even* and *odd* array - so that's why you have `gem++` (index for the even-array) and `gem1++` (index for the odd-array).

Comment: There is no direct way to shorten the code - not without changing the "data types" you are using. (you could use an `ArrayList<Double>` instead of a `double[]` but this is probably too far for now). What you could do, however, is rename the variable. It is difficult to understand because the names are meaningless. (see my edit)

Comment: You are amazing thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I was having a hard time understanding arrays because I just studied java last week and I tried so hard searching but I still can't comprehend it but I get it now! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome :)  If I might give you one last hint, the way the arrays are declared here is confusing: `double a[] = ..`  It is perfectly valid but in Java it is "common" to write: `double[] a =..`. The braces `[ ]` go directly after the *type*. So you can read it like: "double-array *a*" . Because it is "an array of doubles called *a*". When you write `double a[]` (braces after the name), you might read it "double a-array", which sounds more like "an array of *a*s" (which doesn't make sense). Later, when the code is getting more complex you might depend on such standards to  understand it.